# How to imitate the html BR tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello right now I have 3 things in the body after the div.

A button and two images. What I want to do is for them to have a new line so the button is in one line, the image is in their own line and the second image is in their own line also.

I tried `document.write("<BR>")` but it just completely breaks my code.here is the current code

```
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.innerHTML = "Do Something";
document.body.appendChild(button)


var img7 = document.createElement('img')
img7.src = 'g.png'
document.body.appendChild(img7)


var img8 = document.createElement('img')
img8.src = 'h.png'
document.body.appendChild(img8)
```

it is in pure javascript so there i can't use `<br>` to break a new line

Comment: Can't you just style it with CSS? A block element will span 100% width by default...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create and append a `<br>` in JavaScript the same way you did for each `<img>`:

```
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.innerHTML = "Do Something";
document.body.appendChild(button)

var br = document.createElement('br')
document.body.appendChild(br)

var img7 = document.createElement('img')
img7.src = 'g.png'
document.body.appendChild(img7)

document.body.appendChild(br.cloneNode())

var img8 = document.createElement('img')
img8.src = 'h.png'
document.body.appendChild(img8)
```